# ASM X86, linux, открыть файл: не получается!

Tags: linux, c, ассемблер, syscall

Господа, я пытаюсь постичь магию сисколов (syscalls).

В языке C все не очень сложно.

я попробовал сделать эту - прямо скажем - нехитрую операцию на ассемблере раза четыре. я потратил на это два дня.

я прочитал несколько советов, в в них буква в букву написано одно и тоже. Не получается.

читал вот это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312290/how-to-open-a-file-in-assembler-and-modify-it
и вот это: [Как открыть файл в ассемблере и модифицировать его?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8312290/4827341)

Что я делаю.

я создаю на диске директорю asm, захожу туда, создаю там один файл с названием test.asm

буквально такой:

```
    bits 64
    global _start

    section .bss

    section .rodata
    filename: db "test.asm", 0;

    section .text

    _start:

    mov eax, 5               ;   sys_open
    mov ebx, filename        ;   const char *filename
    mov ecx, 0               ;read mode
    syscall
```

Здесь написано: положи в ebx ссылку на имя файла, положи номер системного вызова (5, открытие файла) в eax, положи режим открытия а ecx. Имя - совпадает с именем ассемблерного файла. То есть не быть такого файла в директории не может. Имя - null terminated.

Потом я компилирую и собраю программу:

```
    nasm -felf64 test.asm -o test.o
    ld test.o -o test
```

Потом я запускаю дебаггер:

```
    edb --run test
```

Потом я 4 раза нажимаю на клавишу F8 - сделать шаг.
Дохожу до syscall.
И всегда получаю в eax код ошибки.

Картинку дебаггера - прилагаю.

Что я делал: я попробовал менять режми открытия. Не влияет.

я попробовал взять сишный код

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    int main(){
        int input_fd = open ("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
        return 0;
    }
```

собрать его командой `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O1 foo.c` и посмотреть в получившийся файл - но там ТАКАЯ МЕШАНИНА всего, несмотря на отсутствие оптимизации, что я сдался.

я не понимаю, чего этой железной дуре не хватвает в моей прекрасной программе из четрых команд асембелра? То есть, я понимаю, что я что то делаю не так. Но я не могу понять, что именно.

Может, сискол неправильный?

Проверим и эту гипотезу. Действительно, вот в этой статье

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254949/assembly-code-to-open-file-wrong

пишут, что "коды сисколов для 64 битного режима отличаются от кодов для 32 битного" (а я, коненчно же, слишком горд, чтобы писать для 32 бит. И вообще, я бы хотел посмотреть в глаза людям, которые склонны к столь дикой смене стандартов - зачем, черт побери, зачем менять коды привычных сисколов?)

Итак,

```
    mov eax, 2               ;   sys_open
    mov ebx, filename        ;   const char *filename
    mov ecx, 0               ;read mode
    syscall
```

Результат - не меняется. По прежнему после вызова syscall в регистре eax находится код ошибки.

Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Спасибо.

[image: edb с кодом ошибки]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На amd64 отличаются не только номера системных вызовов, но и регистры, через которые передаются параметры. Аргументы системного вызова распихиваются по регистрам в порядке: `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8`,`r9`. Открытие файла будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
mov rax, 2               ;   sys_open
mov rdi, filename        ;   const char *filename
mov rsi, 0               ; read mode
mov rdx, 0               ; permissions
syscall
```

Answer (score 4):

А ларчик просто открывался...

В общем, документацию читать надо.

Вот пример, когда код работает:

```
    bits 64
    global _start

    section .bss

    section .rodata
    filename: db "test.asm", 0;

    section .text

    _start:

    mov rax, 2               ;   sys_open
    mov rdi, filename        ;   const char *filename
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdx, 0               ;read mode
    syscall
```

Не только номера сисколов поменялись, но и регистры, в которые надо помещать аргументы. Как только я нашел хоть чуть чуть понятную таблицу с аргументами и номерами сисколов для 64-битного режима - все встало на свои места.

Таблица:

https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Comment: тот замечательный момент, когда мучаешься 2 дня, полчаса составляешь вопрос для SO, описывая свои мытарства, и через 5 минут находишь ответ =)

Comment: @Fat-Zer - Спасибо, без Вашей поддержки мне было бы труднее его найти! Тут еще и эти два дня не только этим занимаешься, что додбавляет эмоций...